# How to define a fixed step between consecutive labels on the X axis?

Tags: java, android, mpandroidchart

I'm using the library `mpandroidchart` to plot a series of data on a line chart. The series is formed by point (x,y) where x represents the time (in seconds), and y represents a temperature.
(The x values are random, and so there is not a max common divisor).

[image]

My attempt. As you can see, the labels on the Y's axis are well displayed, with a step of 10 unit. This doesn't hold for the X's axis.

So, I would like to define the step for the labels on the X's axis how to do, but I have no idea, and it seems an unsupported setting by the library. Can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add:

```java
chart.getXAxis().setLabelsToSkip(10);
```

Replace '10' by the number of labels you want to skip.

Comment: this method doesn't exist... at least in the latest release of the lib

Comment: did you find any solution?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `XAxisValueFormater` and `setLabelsToSkip()` for this:

```
public class MyCustomXAxisValueFormatter implements XAxisValueFormatter {

    @Override
    public String getXValue(String original, int index, ViewPortHandler viewPortHandler) {
        viewPortHandler.setMaximumScaleX(24f);
        float scalex=viewPortHandler.getScaleX();

        if(scalex>=2.6f && scalex <3f)
            mChart.getXAxis().setLabelsToSkip(47);
        if(scalex>=3f && scalex <4f)
            mChart.getXAxis().setLabelsToSkip(35);
        if(scalex>=4f && scalex <11f)
            mChart.getXAxis().setLabelsToSkip(23);
        if(scalex>=11f && scalex <18f)
            mChart.getXAxis().setLabelsToSkip(11);
        if(scalex>=18f && scalex <24f)
            mChart.getXAxis().setLabelsToSkip(5);

        return original;
    }
}
```

It sets how many X Axis labels should be skiped depending on how much chart is zoomed in or out.

Hope it helps!